# Find function value in rstudio

Tags: r, function, solver

I have the function

```
fun1 <- function(x) -(2 * (sin(x) * cos(x)))
```

Now I want to find for which values of x, fun1=0

Also, I have a function

```
fun2 <- function(x) 2 * (cos(x) * sin(x))
```

Now I also want to find, for which values BOTH fun1=0 AND fun2=0

Hope someone can help

Regards,

s

Comment: Do you have any range of x?

Comment: hi you can check rootSolve package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rootSolve/vignettes/rootSolve.pdf

Comment: You can search for roots of `fun3 <- function(x) abs(fun1(x)) +abs(fun2(x))` .. there are many ways to achieve this with R. But in your case, it is obvious that whenever `cos(x)` or `sin(x)` is 0 then both `fun1(x)` and `fun2(x)` are 0, and if none of the cos or sin in 0 then none of your functions will return 0.. so no need to calculate anything : the roots are 0, pi/2, pi, 3*pi/2 (modulo 2*pi).

Comment: I know this one is obious that is why I want to learn the programming with this simple one to know the code is correct for more advanced.
How would you suggest the code should be for solving fun3 which you mention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `uniroot` to find the root of a function. In this case, there are multiple roots for both functions (an infinite amount actually), so you will have to specify an interval. You can do this with visual inspection. Let's first plot the functions on the range `(0,6)`:

```
fun1 <- function(x) -(2 * (sin(x) * cos(x)))
fun2 <- function(x) 2 * (cos(x) * sin(x))

x = seq(0,6,0.01)
plot(x,fun1(x),col='blue')
points(x,fun2(x),col='red')
```

[image]

We can see that visually that it looks like `fun1` and `fun2` intersect around `y=0` in for example the range `c(1,2)`. So let's find their `x`-values when `y = 0` in that range:

```
uniroot(fun1,c(1,2))$root
uniroot(fun2,c(1,2))$root
```

They both return `1.570795`, so we have found an `x-value` where `fun1(x) = fun2(x) = 0`. Hope this helps!

Comment: It is very nice answer, thank you.But here I am testing first one of the functions and then the next one. Is it possible both at the same time?

Comment: Well, as @MrSmithGoesToWashington mentions in the comments, you could create a function `fun3(x)` that is defined as the difference between the functions. But note that `fun3(x)=0` does not imply that both `fun1(x)=0` and `fun2(x)=0` , but rather that their difference is 0; They could also both be 4.

Comment: So there is no package or solver in r there an handle both in one line?

Comment: Not that I know of. But I am not omniscient ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In x the values that you want to test

```
x<-seq(0,100,by=0.01)
```

Test fun1

```
f1<-x[round(unlist(lapply(x,FUN = fun1)),2)==0]
```

Test fun2

```
f2<-x[round(unlist(lapply(x,FUN = fun2)),2)==0]
```

Intersaction

```
f1[f1 %in% f2]
 [1]  0.00  1.57  3.14  4.71 15.71 17.28 18.85 20.42 21.99 23.56 34.56 36.13 37.70 39.27 40.84 42.41 43.98 54.98 56.55 58.12
[21] 59.69 61.26 62.83 75.40 76.97 78.54 80.11 81.68 83.25 94.25 95.82 97.39 98.96
```

Comment: This one only return one solution (0), but since this i periodic there are more on the given sequence of x.
Is it possible to get all values of x which solves the function in the sequence?

Comment: Using round(,2) in lapply you have more results. I'm changing the answer according to this.